# How to keep SQLite database on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: sqlite, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I have an application running on the Raspberry Pi with Windows IoT, but every time I give deploy on a new version or when I restart the Raspberry, all SQLite database is deleted. I saw something about that, by default, it creates temporary seats. How to keep the data permanently?
I used exactly the tutorial the following link http://blog.chrisbriggsy.com/Using-SQLITE-in-Windows-10-IoT-Core-Insider-Preview/

Comment: Are you copying a fresh/empty database alongside your application when you deploy?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I start doing this
    path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");
    conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path);

And when I do a count of tables, after having already created the database and restarted the Pi, doesn't come any table.

Comment: You did not answer my question. Are you *deploying* a copy of your database?

Comment: I'm sorry @LasseV.Karlsen, but I honestly do not understand. I did only what's in the example of the link.

Comment: And you did not add the database file to your project and set it to "copy always" or anything like that?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I don't. I figured it would be created the file in that new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection. Because when I do it and create the tables during the program running, everything is ok, the problem is when I reboot everything, whitout creating the tables, I thought it kept the previous database.